# Create dynamically-named SQL table with POCO

Tags: c++, sqlite, poco-libraries

The following code creates a table named "test" in POCO:

```
#include "Poco/Data/Session.h"
#include "Poco/Data/SQLite/Connector.h"

#include <string>

using namespace Poco::Data::Keywords;
using Poco::Data::Session;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Poco::Data::SQLite::Connector::registerConnector();
    Session session("SQLite", "test.db");
    session << "CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER)", now;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to write a function which creates tables named according to the given arguments. I would have thought to use

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Poco::Data::SQLite::Connector::registerConnector();
    Session session("SQLite", "test.db");
    std::string name = "test";
    session << "CREATE TABLE ? (id INTEGER)", bind(name), now;
    return 0;
}
```

Using the wildcard character and replacing it with the given name. As I understand it, I shouldn't even need `bind` (which copies the given value) and `use` should be sufficient since the statement is terminated with `now`, but no matter.

Regardless of which keyword I use (`use`, `bind`, `useRef`), the program throws an "SQL error or missing database" error.

I've also tried creating a `Statement` and have it create the table, but no change.

Am I doing something wrong? Is wildcard substitution not allowed with this call? Do I have to modify the call manually?

Should it be relevant, as can be inferred from my `#includes`, I'm using SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Using the `printf` format specifiers works here. So the statement should be

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Poco::Data::SQLite::Connector::registerConnector();
    Session session("SQLite", "test.db");
    std::string name = "test";
    session << "CREATE TABLE %s (id INTEGER)", name, now;
    return 0;
}
```

This requires recompiling the statement every time it's called, so I'm not sure why this is necessary (what if I wanted to create multiple similar tables?), but *c'est la vie*.